# Why does windows shell's for command replace semicolons?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a small script which replaces a value in windows' path.
Using some sed to replace it is fine (I've got the proper variable):

```
echo %path% | sed "s/jvms\\[^^\]\+/jvms\\%1/"
```

This works fine. However, I want to assign that to a new path variable. The way to do that should be

```
for /f "delims=" %%B in ('echo %path% ^| sed "s/windows/C64/"' ) do call set replaced=%%B
echo %replaced%
```

Note that the | is escaped as it should. However, the new `replaced` variable has all the semicolons replaced by spaces. Hence, the output of `echo %replaced%` is something like `c:\C64 c:\program files c:\otherdirectory` instead of `c:\C64;c:\program files;c:\otherdirectory`

This already happens when I don't use any sed, so

```
for /f "delims=" %%B in ('echo %path%' ) do call set replaced=%%B
echo %replaced%
```

then returns `c:\Windows c:\program files c:\otherdirectory`

How can I ensure that the semicolon is not replaced by spaces?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using cmd.exe rather than PowerShell?

Comment: Is there any reason using `sed` for replacing a string in environment variable `PATH` by another string instead of using cmd internal command `set` to do the string substitution? Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `set /?` and read the output help explaining also how to use this command to replace all occurrences of a string in an environment variable value by another string case-insensitive. The Windows command processor even supports string substitutions using `set` syntax for the string value of an environment variable anywhere on a command line.

Comment: None of these comments are related to the question. Why cmd? Why not? Replacement with set is hard to do since it does *not* support regexes, so replacing an arbitrary, unknown value is not trivial.

Comment: Why not…because [[tag:cmd]], and therefore a [[tag:batch-file]], doesn't have any regex support, _(unless you introduce a tool which does)_. If you need regex support, choose something which can do so in the first instance, like the built-in [[tag:powershell]] console instead. The comments are not related to the question, they are to advise you that you are trying to achieve a task in a non standard way. Whilst you may be aware of that, and want to do it the hard way, all future readers do not, and for that reason the comments, and my answer, are potentially useful to them if not yourself.

Comment: "Why cmd? Why not?" Because there are better tools available. The time investment in learning to use the superior tool will be rewarded in the long term. Also, it benefits other readers to know they don't have to struggle with the arcane cmd.exe "language" with its various parsing quirks (one of which you ran into in this very question).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I wanted to know why. I choose cmd over powershell, because i'm more comfortable with it (old dos user, sue me ;)), and I'd like something working in the lowest common denominator. I could use power shell or even more, but it would require others to use powershell, or install stuff. I don't want that. I want to put in some effort, learn a (cool?) quirk, and have something that 'just works'. So... 'better' is a bit subjective to me. For me, this is 'better', YMWV ;)
That 'cool' quirk may indicate that I should use something else. But I want to know if it can be done, and it can

Comment: 1) PowerShell is already present starting in Windows 7 and later (nothing to install--just pointing that out). 2) You say "I want to put in some effort" - IMO your efforts are far better spent learning a far superior tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cmd` parser considers semicolons (as well as commas, equal signs and TABs) as token separators. The `for /f` command undergoes one round of parsing, where the separators are replaced with spaces. For example, `for /f "delims=" %%B in ('echo a;b==c,,,d') do echo %%B` results in `a b c d`.

One way to avoid the replacement is to quote the argument, then unquote the `%%~B` token. For the second example, `for /f "delims=" %%B in ('echo "%path%"' ) do set "replaced=%%~B"` will work as expected.

Comment: thank you! I suspected as much but could not figure out how to avoid it. I've worked around it in the meantime, but this is vital to know going forward.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, there's no need for a third party stream editor, or find and replace utility, for this task. You can use variable expansion and substitution, and this will also negate the need for a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) too:

Example:

```sh
Set "replaced=%PATH::\Windows=:\C64%"
```

If the replacement string is being received as the first input argument then, you'd use delayed variable expansion.

Example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "replaced=!PATH::\Windows=:\%~1!"
Echo %replaced%
```

Comment: That is not an answer to this question.

Comment: Correct @KoosGadellaa, its a solution to achiving the required result without having to workaround a problem, which did not need to be worked around!